# Creating a two dimensional array with given width and height in Javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

How do you write a function given arguments width, height and value that make a two dimensional array with that given width and height and fill every spot with a given value?

```
function createGrid(width, height, value) {
    var array = new Array(height);

    for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        array[i] = new Array(width);
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < height; k++) {
            array[k][j] = value;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

This is what I wrote, but I'm wondering why I can't just write something like `var array = new array(width, height)`. Why isn't such simple syntax possible in Javascript?

Comment: Because that's how it was designed.

Comment: Is this possible in other languages? Who do you think they would opt for such an odd design though?

Comment: In JS this not possible mainly because JS doesn't have multidimensional arrays. You can emulate them with nested arrays though.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a function like this:

```js
function createGrid(width, height, value) {
    return Array.apply(null, { length: height }).map(function () {
        return Array.apply(null, { length: width }).map(function () {
            return value;
        });
    });
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(createGrid(5, 4, 42), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```